# Get images from rss feed

Tags: android, image, rss

I'm trying to display the images of rss feed with `Android Studio` but I don't know how to do this. I can get all the other items but I don't know why I can't get the images. Can you help me please? 
This is my `Handler`:

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

final int state_unknown = 0;
final int state_title = 1;
final int state_description = 2;
final int state_link = 3;
final int state_pubdate = 4;
final int state_enclosure = 5;
final int state_url = 6;
int currentState = state_unknown;

RSSFeed feed;
RSSItem item;

boolean itemFound = false;

RSSHandler(){
}

RSSFeed getFeed(){
    return feed;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    feed = new RSSFeed();
    item = new RSSItem();

}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        itemFound = true;
        item = new RSSItem();
        currentState = state_unknown;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")){
        currentState = state_url;
    }
    //{
      //  if (!attributes.getValue("url").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
         //   feed.setImage(attributes.getValue("url"));
        //} else {
       //    feed.setImage("");
        //}
      //  currentState = state_image;
    //}
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){
        currentState = state_enclosure;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
        currentState = state_title;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
        currentState = state_description;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
        currentState = state_link;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")){
        currentState = state_pubdate;
    }
    else{
        currentState = state_unknown;
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        feed.addItem(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);

    if (itemFound==true){
 // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_url:
                item.setUrl(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_enclosure:
                item.setEnclosure(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_title:
                item.setTitle(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_description:
                item.setDescription(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_link:
                item.setLink(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
 // not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_url:
                feed.setUrl(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_enclosure:
                feed.setEnclosure(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_title:
                feed.setTitle(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_description:
                feed.setDescription(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_link:
                feed.setLink(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                feed.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    currentState = state_unknown;
}
```

**EDIT**
*how I show images*

```
   try {
    URL url = new URL(web.get(position).getEnclosure()+web.get(position).getUrl());
      HttpGet httpRequest;

      httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpResponse response = httpclient
             .execute(httpRequest);

      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
      InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();
      ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enclosure);
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

       } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: Android Studio is just the IDE you use and is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: It's only to be more specific ;)

Comment: Anyway, you know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted isn't really relevant to the problem, you should have already fetched the feed and parsed it to extract the urls, you can then do the following, however I would recommend Picasso from Square instead which will do all the heavy lifting AND add functionality like caching and interrupting requests automatically - http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
try {
    InputStream inStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, "my source name");
    return d;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See your edits why? This solution is valid, do you think your new question changes that? As for the edit's themselves - extremely bad - get view can be called DOZENS of times, all on the UI thread - do NOT do network activities in that method (or any time on the UI thread). DO use the view holder pattern to save on expensive find view calls and DO do caching!

Comment: Also the 'view' param and the 'viewrow' you created are one and the same - it's recycling! - check if view is empty and inflate into that variable if it is, otherwise don't do any inflating!

Comment: I only wanted to show you how I was trying to show images in my custom listview (don't get angry ;)) I'm a newbie

Comment: I'm not angry at all, but just trying to stress the importance of the points I've just made. If you don't pay attention android will show a notification saying the application is not responding and asking the user whether to close it

Comment: If you're a newbie leave difficult things like this until you're better acquainted with the OS, until then use Picasso which I've linked above. I usually don't like answers which just say to use a 3rd party library as they just encourage debate, but I use picasso in many projects its great, lightweight and will take care of some of the problems I mentioned

Comment: Are you calling myImageView.setImageDrawable(d) with the result?

Comment: Yes,try {
            InputStream inStream = (InputStream) new URL(web.get(position).getEnclosure()+web.get(position).getUrl()).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, "my source name");
            ImageView img = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.enclosure);
            img.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

Comment: If you've checked for any Exceptions and are waiting long enough for it to fetch the image, then I don't have any more ideas except make sure the URL it's creating is complete and valid. I'm not sure what web.get(position).getEnclosure()+web.get(position) is doing really

Comment: If my answer has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you